# Filter large list based on date time

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have the following Items class:

```
public class Item
{
   public Item()
   {
   }

   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Price {get; set;}
   public DateTime CreatedDate {get; set;}

}
```

and then in my code I have `List<Item> items` that contains `A LOT` of items of type `Item`, my question is what you recommend as the best way/practice of sorting/filtering the items in the list based on CreatedDate for the following scenarios:

- all items where the CreatedDate is before date x
- all items where the CreatedDate after date x
- all items where the CreatedDate between date x and date y

P.S. What about if I will mentione also the time? Like before/after/between date x time y ?

Comment: I tried the DateTime.Compare in basic If condition ... so just wanted to know what is the optimal aproach ...

Comment: This looks fairly like a homework, but not sure :P

Comment: I wouldn't call `DateTime.Compare`, when `DateTime` overloads `>`, `>=` etc helpfully.

Comment: There will be a lot of answers using Linq to do linear searches, which is fine if it's fast enough (only testing will tell you that). If the list is very long and you do a lot of searches, and also if the list doesn't change much, then it *might* be worth sorting it by CreatedDate and doing binary searches to find the required items. But try one of the Linq answers first (I'm not going to waste time writing an answer that uses binary searching if it's not needed ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet Considering the lazy evaluation of LINQ and the non-caching working of the operators of LINQ-to-Objects, it's like giving him a handgun and telling him "the hole in that direction, please".

Comment: @xanatos: I don't see why... I would definitely start with a *simple* LINQ-based solution, and then consider optimizing later. Unless he's going to iterate over the result more than once, materializing the results is pointless... and if you want to materialize the results, that's very easy to do.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `LINQ`:

```
var beforeDateX = items
    .Where(i => i.CreatedDate.Date < DateX); // remove the .Date if you want to include the time
var afterDateX = items
    .Where(i => i.CreatedDate.Date > DateX);
var betweenDates = items
    .Where(i => i.CreatedDate.Date >= DateX && i.CreatedDate.Date <= DateY);
```

You can use a `foreach` or methods like `ToList` to execute the query and materialize the result.

```
foreach(Item i in beforeDateX)
    Console.WriteLine("Name:{0} CreatedDate:{1}", i.Name, i.CreatedAt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Linq:

```
var itemsBefore = items.Where(i => i.CreatedDate <= timeBefore);
var itemsAfter = items.Where(i => i.CreatedDate >= timeAfter);
var itemsBetween = items.Where(i => i.CreatedDate >= timeStart && i.CreatedDate <= timeEnd);
```

For ordering

```
var ordrered = items.OrderBy(i => i.CreatedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have a `List<>`, I suggest:

```
List<Item> itemsBefore = items.FindAll(i => i.CreatedDate <= timeBefore);
List<Item> itemsAfter = items.FindAll(i => i.CreatedDate >= timeAfter);
List<Item> itemsBetween = items.FindAll(i => i.CreatedDate >= timeStart && i.CreatedDate <= timeEnd);
```

there is a subtle difference between what I suggested and what the other have suggested.

The `.Where` method doesn't "cache" the returned list, so if you do:

```
var filtered = items.Where(condition);

foreach (var item in filtered)
{
}

foreach (var item in filtered)
{
}
```

your whole list will be parsed twice to search for the items that make the condition true. To solve this "problem" (sometimes it could be a problem) you can add a `.ToList()` after the `.Where()`

The `List<>.FindAll()` returns a new `List<>` with only the selected items. So you can enumerate it how many times you want, because it has been "materialized".

Answer (score 1):

All the LINQ approaches are great, but they iterate the list 3 times. If there are really LOT of items, then maybe an old-fashioned way will be more efficient (that is, if you want all three scenarios at once, otherwise the LINQ answers are the way to go):

```
List<Item> before = new List<Item>();
List<Item> after = new List<Item>();
List<Item> between = new List<Item>();

foreach (var item in Items)
{
  if (item.CreatedDate <= timeBefore)
  {
    before.Add(item);
  }
  else if (item.CreatedDate >= timeAfter)
  {
    after.Add(item);
  }
  else
  {
    between.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [LINQ Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Item item1 = new Item() { CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 11, 10), Id = "1", Name = "foo1", Price = "10.00" };
    Item item2 = new Item() { CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 11, 11), Id = "2", Name = "foo2", Price = "11.00" };
    Item item3 = new Item() { CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 11, 12), Id = "3", Name = "foo3", Price = "12.00" };
    Item item4 = new Item() { CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 11, 13), Id = "4", Name = "foo4", Price = "13.00" };
    Item item5 = new Item() { CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 11, 14), Id = "5", Name = "foo5", Price = "14.00" };
    Item item6 = new Item() { CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 11, 15), Id = "6", Name = "foo6", Price = "15.00" };
    Item item7 = new Item() { CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 11, 16), Id = "7", Name = "foo7", Price = "16.00" };
    Item item8 = new Item() { CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 11, 17), Id = "8", Name = "foo8", Price = "17.00" };

    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    items.Add(item1);
    items.Add(item2);
    items.Add(item3);
    items.Add(item4);
    items.Add(item5);
    items.Add(item6);
    items.Add(item7);
    items.Add(item8);

    List<Item> filtered = ItemsBeforeDate(items, new DateTime(2010, 11, 16));
    foreach (Item i in filtered)
    {
        Console.Write(i.Name);
    }

    Console.Read();
}

public static List<Item> ItemsBeforeDate(List<Item> items, DateTime beforeDate)
{
    return items.Where(i => i.CreatedDate < beforeDate).ToList();
}

public static List<Item> ItemsAfterDate(List<Item> items, DateTime afterDate)
{
    return items.Where(i => i.CreatedDate > afterDate).ToList();
}

public static List<Item> ItemsBetweenDates(List<Item> items, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return items.Where(i => i.CreatedDate >= startDate && i.CreatedDate <= endDate).ToList();
}
```

Prints:

> foo1
>     foo2
>     foo3
>     foo4
>     foo5
>     foo6

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at [Enumerable METHODS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx)

For Filtering use the [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

```
list.Where(x=>x.CreatedDate < yourDate).ToList();
```

For [Ordering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

```
list.OrderBy(x=>x.CreatedDate).ToList();
```

Comment: I would actually order it before doing the where clause for branch-prediction friendliness! :)

Comment: i am just telling him the methods of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the third way is OK.

But if you don't want filter you can implement a pagination when you retrieve your list. Because if you put a large date range you don't resolve your performance issue.